# jQuery DataTables: Save the same state for multiple tables

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want when I change the state of a table (example: number of lines per page), the change is recorded and applied to all the tables. I tried with `stateSave: true`, but it is saved only for the table I made the change.

```
$('#currentTab').dataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    stateSave: true
});

$('#twoWaveTab').dataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
     stateSave: true
});

$('#EvolTab').dataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    stateSave: true
});
```

How I can save the same state for a table and at the same time for other generic tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [stateSaveParams](http://datatables.net/reference/event/stateSaveParams) event and [state.save()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/state.save%28%29) API method.

There is no direct way to copy state of one table into another, you need to set each state property individually. The code below only copies page length from one table to others with `$(this).DataTable().page.len(data.length)`.

You need to replace `example1`, `example2` and `example3` with IDs of your tables (`currentTab`, `twoWaveTab` and `EvolTab`).

```
var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    stateSave: true
});

var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    stateSave: true
});

var table3 = $('#example3').DataTable({
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    stateSave: true
});

var is_save_in_progress = false;
var $tables = $('#example1, #example2, #example3');
$tables
   .on( 'stateSaveParams.dt', function (e, settings, data){
      // Save DOM element
      var that = this;

      // If state saving is not in progress
      if(!is_save_in_progress){
         is_save_in_progress = true;

         // Iterate over all tables
         $tables.each(function(index){

            // If table is other than the initial table
            if(this.id !== that.id){

               // Set page length, save state and redraw the table
               $(this).DataTable()
                  .page.len(data.length)
                  .state.save()
                  .draw(false);
            }         
         });

         // Indicate that state saving is over
         is_save_in_progress = false;
      }            
   });
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d32j6bLe/1/) for demonstration.

Comment: i have a probleme when i copy this code : an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'len' of undefined

Comment: @YoussefMayoufi, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d32j6bLe/1/) for demonstration of working code. Modify this JSFiddle or give a link to a page that you're working on to illustrate the error you're getting.

Comment: i think the problem that i use this plugin in a angularjs controller so, no load page ! how can i resolve this probleme :(